# Create dataframe from list in pyspark: ValueError

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a list into a dataframe in pyspark so that I can then join it onto a larger dataframe as a column.  The data in the list are randomly generated names as so:

```
from faker import Faker
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

faker = Faker("en_GB")

list1 = [faker.first_name() for _ in range(0, 100)]
firstname = sc.parallelize([list1])

schema = StructType([
    StructField('FirstName', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(firstname, schema)

display(df)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> PythonException: 'ValueError: Length of object (100) does not match with length of fields (1)'.

Any ideas on what's causing this and how to fix it appreciated!

Many thanks,

Carolina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `ValueError` because you're passing a list with one element that is a list of 100 names to `parallelize` instead of passing a list of 100 elements, each element contains a list of one name.

If for instance `Faker.first_name()` returns `'John'`, then `'Henry'`, then `'Jade'`, etc..., your `[list1]` argument contains `[['John', 'Henry', 'Jade', ...]]`.

When you pass such list to `createDataFrame` method, it tries to create a dataframe with one row having 100 columns. As your schema defines only one column, it fails.

Solution here is to either to create directly dataframe from `list1` as in [PApostol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101306/6807769), or to change how you build `list1` so you have a list of 100 lists containing one name each instead of a list of one list of 100 names:

```
from faker import Faker
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

faker = Faker("en_GB")

list1 = [[faker.first_name()] for _ in range(0, 100)]
firstname = sc.parallelize(list1)

schema = StructType([
    StructField('FirstName', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(firstname, schema)

display(df)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and makes sense!  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `pyspark` tries to create a dataframe with 100 columns (the length of `firstname`) but you're only providing one column in your `schema`. Try without parallelize:

```
list1 = [faker.first_name() for _ in range(0, 100)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(list1, schema)
```

or if you do want to parallelize, try:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

list1 = [faker.first_name() for _ in range(0, 100)]
firstname = sc.parallelize([list1])

firstname_row = firstname.map(lambda x: Row(x))
df = spark.createDataFrame(firstname_row, schema)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response!  This works but I end up with all the values in one row.  I would like each of the 100 values spread over 100 rows.  Any ideas on how to achieve this?  Thanks :)